# How do I pass data to a screen while using auto_route in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a home page with 5 bottomnavbar items (just like instagram) and I need to pass a boolean to one of the pages. I'm using auto_route to navigate.

```
 AutoRoute(
  path: '/home',
  name: 'HomeRouter',
  page: Home,
  children: [
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'timeline',
      name: 'TimelineRouter',
      page: Timeline,
     ),

      AutoRoute(
      path: 'profile',
      name: 'ProfileRouter',
      page: EmptyRouterPage,
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: '',
          page: Profile,    <-----
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: ":currentUserId",
          name: "EditProfileRouter",
          page: EditProfile,
        ),
        
      ],
    ),
   ],
  )
```

I need to pass a boolean to the profile page but I'm not sure how to do that using auto_route. Any hints?
When I passed a boolean, the page received a null value for some reason. What could be the possible reason for getting a null value?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is coming straight from the [auto_route API documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#passing-arguments):

> AutoRoute automatically detects and handles your page arguments for
> you, the generated route object will deliver all the arguments your
> page needs including path/query params.
>
> e.g. The following page widget will take an argument of type Book.

```
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {  
  const BookDetailsPage({required this.book});              
  
  final Book book;  
  ...
```

> The generated BookDetailsRoute will deliver the same arguments to it's
> corresponding page.

```
router.push(BookDetailsRoute(book: book));
```

Comment: So in your case `BookDetailsPage` represents your `Profile` class. and the `Book book` variable needs to be replaced by `bool var_name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
I used a bool value on the profile page to remove the leading icon while I am calling on the bottom navbar so I am sharing my code I Hope this will work for you.Thanks
    
    ////Bottom Navigation page
        
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';
        import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/home/Home.dart';
        import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/profile/Profile.dart';
        import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/setting/Setting.dart';
        
        
        
        class EmployeeBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
          const EmployeeBottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          _EmployeeBottomNavBarState createState() => _EmployeeBottomNavBarState();
        }
        
        class _EmployeeBottomNavBarState extends State<EmployeeBottomNavBar> {
          int pageIndex = 0;
          bool visible = true;
        
          List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[EmployeeHome(), EmployeeProfile(leadingIcon: false,), Setting()];
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
                body: pageList[pageIndex],
                bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                    fixedColor: Colors.redAccent[400],
                    currentIndex: pageIndex,
                    onTap: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        pageIndex = value;
                      });
                    },
                    // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        
                          activeIcon: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.home,
                              color: AppColors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                          ),
                          label: ""),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Color(0xff2161c0),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              color: AppColors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                          ),
                          label: ""),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 80,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.settings,
                              color: AppColors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.settings,
                            color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                          ),
                          label: ""),
                    ]
                )
            );
          }
        }
    
    ///////Profile page
    
    import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppStrings.dart';
    
    
    class EmployeeProfile extends StatefulWidget {
      final bool leadingIcon;
      EmployeeProfile({Key? key, required this.leadingIcon}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _EmployeeProfileState createState() => _EmployeeProfileState();
    }
    
    class _EmployeeProfileState extends State<EmployeeProfile> {
      bool? visible;
      double? _width;
      File ?_image;
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      Future<void>_showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context)
      {
        return showDialog(context: context,builder: (BuildContext context){
    
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Choose option",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: [
                  Divider(height: 1,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context,_getImage(ImageSource.gallery));
                    },
                    title: Text("Gallery",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
                  ),
    
                  Divider(height: 1,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context,_getImage(ImageSource.gallery));
                    },
                    title: Text("Camera",style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.camera,color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),);
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: _width!,
                color: AppColors.white,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Material(
                          color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                          elevation: 15,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 180,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                              // AppColors.blue,
                              borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          // color: AppColors.green,
                          width: _width! * 0.90,
                          height: 140,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    AppStrings.personalInformation,
                                    // "Informations personelles",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff919AAA),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 50,
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          AppStrings.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          AppStrings.email,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          AppStrings.phone,
                                          // "Phone",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 30,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 200,
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "Laure Beno",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "laure.beno@gmail.com",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text("+33 (0)6 45 23 65 77",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                                            )),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: _width! * 0.87,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                AppStrings.myPoetryModes,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.hotelListLightGreyColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "+ " + AppStrings.add,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.hotelListLightGreyColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                            width: _width! * 0.90,
                            child: atmCard(
                                cardName: "VISA",
                                image: "assets/Visa.png",
                                height: 10)),
                        Container(
                            width: _width! * 0.90,
                            child: atmCard(
                                cardName: "Master Card",
                                image: "assets/MasterCard.png",
                                height: 20)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 80,
                        child: _image==null?Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 150,
                              width:_width,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 120,
                                    width: 120,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                                        border: Border.all(color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: AssetImage("assets/managerPicture.jpeg"),fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        )
                                      /*gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topRight,
                              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              colors: [
                                Color(0xff00519E),
                                AppColors.blue,
                                Colors.blue.shade900,
                              ],
                            )*/
                                    ),
                                    /* child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                            child: Image.asset("assets/manager.jpeg",height: 100,width: 100,)
                          //Icon(Icons.person, size: 100),
                          // child: Image.asset("assets/logo/profile.png", fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        ),*/
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: 60,
                              right: 0,
                              left: 100,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  _showChoiceDialog(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: _width,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        height: 35,
                                        width: 35,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: AppColors.profiePicBackground,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
    
                                          //border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue.shade900, width: 2.0),
                                        ),
                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                                          child: Icon(MdiIcons.squareEditOutline,color: AppColors.popUpBlueColor,size: 20,),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),)
                          ],
                        ):Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 150,
                              width:_width,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 120,
                                    width: 120,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        image:  FileImage(_image!),
                                      ),
                                      border: Border.all(color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: 60,
                              right: 0,
                              left: 100,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  _showChoiceDialog(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: _width,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        height: 35,
                                        width: 35,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: AppColors.profiePicBackground,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
    
                                          //border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue.shade900, width: 2.0),
                                        ),
                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                                          child: Icon(MdiIcons.squareEditOutline,color: AppColors.popUpBlueColor,size: 20,),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),)
                          ],
                        )
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 40,
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:8,right: 8),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              widget.leadingIcon == true
                                  ? Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      MdiIcons.arrowLeft,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                              )
                                  : Container(),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                child: Text(AppStrings.myAccount,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        color: AppColors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: Icon(
                                      MdiIcons.pencilOutline,
                                      color: AppColors.white,
                                    )),
                              ),
    
    
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      //ImageSource: Camera and Gallery.
      _getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async
      {
        PickedFile? imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);
    //if user doesn't take any image, just return.
        if (imageFile == null) return;
        setState(
              () {
    //Rebuild UI with the selected image.
            _image = File(imageFile.path);
          },
        );
      }
    
      Widget atmCard({String? image, String? cardName, double? height}) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // Navigator.push(
            //     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Class()));
          },
          child: Card(
            elevation: 2,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, right: 5, left: 5),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              // width: _width! * 0.90,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                // top: 5,
                left: 20,
                // right: 20,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: Colors.white),
    
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    image.toString(),
                    height: height,
                  ),
                  //Icon(Icons.atm,color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.62,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          cardName.toString(),
                          // "MasterCard",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "4******12345678",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: AppColors.hotelListLightGreyColor),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing but you don't seem to be using auto_route library. Under normal circumstances, it's easy to pass values to other classes but auto_route Is making it difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your path arguments like this in autoRoute class :

```
AutoRoute(page: TrackAttendancePage, path: 'track-attendance/:id')
```

Then in your page pass them as argument using @PathParam

```
class TrackAttendancePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String registerId;

  const TrackAttendancePage(@PathParam('id') this.registerId,{Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
}
```